# How do I (efficiently) add a vector to every row of a matrix in Julia?

Tags: julia

Assume I have a vector:

```
> center = rand(3)*4.0+[20.0,0.0,0.0]
[22.465564798443808,2.132417269282639,1.039350032538299]
```

and a matrix:

```
> matr = rand(3,100)
3x100 Array{Float64,2}:
0.553568  0.151356  0.973657   0.682295   …  0.744368  0.663721  0.207874
0.564884  0.313721  0.0210261  0.0998009     0.407483  0.660501  0.701287
0.521986  0.14833   0.199381   0.701672      0.18789   0.573488  0.894083
```

How do I add `center` to every row of `matr`?

`matr + center` requires them to have equal dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply prepend `.` to the `+` which will allow per element addition:

```
matr .+ centre
```

Comment: Why bother asking if you actually know the answer?

Comment: Because I didn't know the answer while typing up the question, but remembered you could do .* and then tried if this works here as well.. should I delete the question? I thought it could help others?

Comment: You answered few seconds after posting the question.

Comment: This is a very simple thing to do in Julia and would be in the first few paragraphs of any good introductory tutorial. I don't think having this question is very useful for anyone.

Comment: Please share a link, because I read plenty of tutorials without this being explained ... and I really don't understand how you can think this is not useful to know ...